# jQuery tools and jQuery interferring

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using a tool called jqplot to render some graphs. Everything worked fine until I included jquery tools into the page. Now, I get an error "Cannot read property 'FunnelRenderer' of undefined ". So I guess that plot4 = $.jqplot isn't working properly now?

```
plot4 = $.jqplot('chart4', [s1], {
    sortData: false,
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.FunnelRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabels: ['&euro;4.9M - B', '&euro;2.8M - C', '&euro;0.6M - D']
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        placement: 'outside'
    },
    grid:{borderWidth:0, shadow:false}

});
```

**What I've tried**

- Updated jquery
- Removed jQuery and left the included jquery in js tools
- Removed jquery from jstools and used original jquery standalone

Nothing seems to work, any ideas? Is ther a variable name somewhere thats overlapping that I need to change?

Comment: The problem is going to be related to the order of the includes, and what each include actually contains. The ideal situation is include jquery, then include jquery tools without jquery, followed by any additional plugins.

Comment: Yup just discovering this now.. I can understand that jquery needs to come before jquery tools, which I had, but why did I need to have jquery tools before the jqplot if they're not related? Also maybe post your comment as answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: well, that indicates that jquery tools is still including it's own jquery. (which makes the initial jquery include pointless)